# Setting up emacs on Mac OSX make error

Tags: macos, emacs, makefile, installation

I'm trying to set up and install emacs 23.4 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.  I'm following the directions given in the INSTALL file.  I successfully ran the ./configure, but then when I tried to run make, it returns the error:

`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

The make program is supposed to create the executable, but it didn't work.  I'm pretty new to this, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't bother installing from source. You'll just get an aneurysm. Instead, try a basic package manager that does it for you: http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: or a built version like Aquamacs

Comment: or even better - http://emacsformacosx.com

Answer (score 2):

The error basically indicates that `configure` did not, in fact, run successfully. Run it again, and examine its output for error messages. A successful run would create a Makefile for your configuration.